# Masking a sprite with an image mask. Phaser

Tags: html, game-engine, phaser-framework, pixi.js

I have a collection of images that creates an animation put in single sprite and an image mask that i want to apply. Do i just have to apply mask to the srpite or to every image in sprite? and How?

Comment: I think you need to give a little more information with your question. When you say "a collection of images" do you mean a set of individual PNG images or do you mean a spritesheet? What have you tried so far? Did you get any errors? What kind of visual effect are you trying to achieve? etc.

Comment: I am also searching this one. No luck so far. I want to mask a sprite with an image. The mask property of sprite accepts only phaser graphics. It is difficult to construct a complex shape with phaser graphics. Another option is alphamask through which we can apply mask for two images, not sprites.

Comment: I m using a spritesheet. I couldnt find any exmaple that mask sprite with another sprite or image. I m trying a mask an animation so that top and bottom of the sprite should blend with background